# Create Gradle task that contains several tasks

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

Is it possible to create a gradle task that runs several tasks? My goal would be to to have a command `cleanAndTestAll` that would be executed like:

```
./gradlew cleanAndTestAll
```

and would be the equivalent of doing:

```
./gradlew clean :unit:test :app:connectedAndroidTestPlayDebug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to define a wrapper task that depends on the tasks you want to run. 
For example adding the following to the root build.gradle :

```
task cleanAndTestAll(dependsOn: [ clean, ':unit:test', ':app:connectedAndroidTestPlayDebug']) { }
```

This task will trigger the two other tasks. and give output like the following:

```
15:31:38: Executing external task 'cleanAndTestAll'...
:clean
:app:connectedAndroidTestPlayDebug 
:unit:test
:cleanAndTestAll 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

If you want to enforce an ordering between the tasks, you could do something like:

```
task cleanAndTestAll(dependsOn: [clean, ':unit:test', ':app:connectedAndroidTestPlayDebug']) { }
tasks.getByPath(':app:connectedAndroidTestPlayDebug').mustRunAfter tasks.getByPath(':unit:test')
```

Find out more about gradle tasks at: 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html

Comment: I ended up arriving at the solution, but you were faster ;) Thanks!